# Logitech Autoclicker, ending Loop

Tags: lua

Im trying to make an Autoclicker with Lua, but it gets stuck in a loop and I can't make it end until I close the program

Any idea how to end the loop when I want?

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)

function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 9 then
        repeat
            MoveMouseTo(27057, 27471)
            Sleep(50)
            PressMouseButton(1)
            Sleep(50)
            ReleaseMouseButton(1)
            Sleep(50)
            MoveMouseTo(33544, 28108)
            Sleep(50)
            PressMouseButton(1)
            Sleep(50)
            ReleaseMouseButton(1)
            Sleep(5000)
        until IsMouseButtonPressed(3)
    end
end
```

Comment: `until IsMouseButtonPressed(3)` - This means the loop works until you press right mouse button.  Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `Sleep(5000)` with the following code:

```
for i = 1, 100
  Sleep(50)
  if IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then break end
end
```

Now you can press and hold RMB to exit the loop.